# Strange output within FirebaseDatabase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the Code showing a strange output:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.name = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.email = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.url = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.dataFromServer = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    [[[_ref child:@"FriendsList"] child:[FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSLog(@"check flist%@", snapshot.value);
        self.dataFromServer = snapshot.value;
        self.uids = [_dataFromServer allValues];
        NSLog(@"%li",[self.uids count]);

        int i = 0;
        while (i != [self.uids count]) {
            NSString *go = [self.uids objectAtIndex:i];
            [[[_ref child:@"UserPools"]child:go] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
                self.dataFromServer = snapshot.value;
                [self.name addObject:[_dataFromServer valueForKey:@"username"]];
                [self.email addObject:[_dataFromServer valueForKey:@"email"]];
                [self.url addObject:[_dataFromServer valueForKey:@"photoURL"]];
                NSLog(@"loop %@%@%@%@",self.name,self.email,self.url,self.uids);
                return;
            }];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        NSLog(@"Down loop%@%@%@%@",self.name,self.email,self.url,self.uids);
        return;
    }];

    NSLog(@"Out side%@%@%@%@",self.name,self.email,self.url,self.uids);

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([myCell class]) bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([myCell class])];
}
```

The output is:

```
2016-10-09 19:34:56.941 obcChat[80961:1055796] Out side(
)(
)(
)(null)
2016-10-09 19:34:57.448 obcChat[80961:1055796] check flist{
xx = dKC8D8GMFiSoPFDCuSzBpEpcjnl1;
}
2016-10-09 19:34:57.449 obcChat[80961:1055796] 1
2016-10-09 19:34:57.449 obcChat[80961:1055796] Down loop(
)(
)(
)(
    dKC8D8GMFiSoPFDCuSzBpEpcjnl1
)
2016-10-09 19:34:58.284 obcChat[80961:1055796] loop (
    Yang
)(
    "test@gmail.com"
)(
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/obcchat-525bf.appspot.com/o/images%2FdKC8D8GMFiSoPFDCuSzBpEpcjnl1?   alt=media&token=b1fbb306-c6f6-4c12-b467-eb4130d533a0"
)(
    dKC8D8GMFiSoPFDCuSzBpEpcjnl1
)
```

Why is the output always printing the last `NSLOG` then other `NSLOG`?

The code is trying to get the data from Firebase and then use the data to get a new data. I am new to coding. Please explain and thanks.

Comment: This is a common error. Firebase is asynchronous in nature and it take time for data to be returned from Firebase. What's happening here is the code after the block executes *faster* than the code inside the block  - the code inside the block only executes once the data has been returned. So in other words, the variables have not been populated in time for the code after the block to display them.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the reply. Is there any way to avoid this ?because I'm trying to pass array to the table view.

Comment: Don't avoid it! Embrace it! That's how firebase works. You need to do updates to your UI *after* Firebase returns the data. So for example, build your tableView dataSource inside the observe block by iterating over the returned values, and when that's done, then reload your tableView. Also, don't call 'return' inside the Firebase blocks and finally, don't think of Firebase events as functions as they are not. They don't behave sequentially like a function would - they are asynchronous.

Comment: @Jay thanks a lot. Now I get the idea.